# Confusion matrix with more than 500 possible categorical outcomes in R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am running naive Bayes classifiers as my all predictors and outcome variables are categorical. Trying to predict which client (around 700 different client names) will buy a specific product. The products have categorical specifications – country origin, color, size, is it in promotion, etc. When I try to see the accuracy with confusion matrix, the results are so messy and long that I could make sense of it. Does anyone have an idea how to visualize confusion matrix with more than 500 possible categorical outcomes? Or maybe there is other way to visualize differently the results?

[image]

```
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(naivebayes)

data <- read.csv("Data.csv")

set.seed(2)
random <- sample(2, nrow(data1), prob = c(0.7, 0.3), replace = T)
data_train <- data[random == 1, ]
data_test <- data[random == 2, ]
data_nb <- naiveBayes(Client.Name ~., data = data_train)
pred_nb <- predict(data_nb, data_test)
confusionMatrix(table(pred_nb, data_test$Client.Name))
```

Comment: Can you either give a sample of confusion matrix or the data to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrix have numerical values for accuracy, you can conveniently visualize it as a heatmap. As accuracy is between 0 and 100%, you don´t even need to normalize it. You can use `ggplot2` or `heatmap.2` package for that purpose.